# Как изменить иконку select

Tags: css

```css
select {
  position: relative;
}

select:after {
  width: 14px;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  background: url(../images/icons/select.png);
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option dislabled>Тип постройки</option>
</select>
```

Как изменить марке в `select`? Пробовал так, но эффекта нет.

Comment: Лучше с нуля свой `select` создай и стилизуй как душе угодно

Answer (score 1):

Эти элементы полностью не кастомезуются. И их отображение будет зависеть от браузера и ос. лучше воспользоваться плагином например https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно просто обернуть в `label` и далее обыграть стилями.

```css
label {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  content:'\25BC';
  display:inline-block;
  color:#000;
  pointer-events:none;
}
label select {
  border: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<label for="myid">
  <select id="myid">
    <option dislabled>Тип постройки</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

Comment: пример лучше привести прямо в тексте ответа (нажав [edit]).